# Strange collision in Breakout

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision-resolution

My Breakout game works fine so far, but I struggle with the collision detection... Well... just with the collision from the ball with the brick...
Here's the relevant code:

```
List<Brick> removeList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Brick b : bricks) {
    if (ball.intersects(b)) {
        float x = b.getX();
        float y = b.getY();
        float width = b.getWidth();
        float height = b.getHeigth();

        Line2D.Float left = new Line2D.Float(x, y, x, y + height);
        Line2D.Float right = new Line2D.Float(x + width, y, x + width, y + height);
        Line2D.Float top = new Line2D.Float(x, y, x + width, y);
        Line2D.Float bottom = new Line2D.Float(x, y + height, x + width, y + height);
        Rectangle2D bounds = ball.getShape().getBounds2D();

        if (bounds.intersectsLine(left)) {
            ball.setVelocityX(-ball.getVelocityX());
            ball.setX(b.getX() - ball.getWidth());
        } else if (bounds.intersectsLine(right)) {
            ball.setVelocityX(-ball.getVelocityX());
            ball.setX(b.getX() + b.getWidth());
        } else if (bounds.intersectsLine(top)) {
            ball.setVelocityY(-ball.getVelocityY());
            ball.setY(b.getY() - ball.getHeigth());
        } else if (bounds.intersectsLine(bottom)) {
            ball.setVelocityY(-ball.getVelocityY());
            ball.setY(b.getY() + b.getHeigth());
        }
        removeList.add(b);
    }
}
bricks.removeAll(removeList);
objects.removeAll(removeList);
```

I thought it would work like this, but sometimes the ball does the wrong collision e.g. when the ball comes from down and it hits the brick near the edge it would collide like it hit from the left!

Is something wrong with my code? Maybe it is the wrong approach?

**EDIT**
Like you can see in the code above I'll get the borders `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` from the x and y coordinates.
After that I check which border was intersected by the ball and determine from which side the brick was hit.

Comment: I strongly suggest you try learning box2d instead of spending your time learning how to implement collisions correctly.

Comment: Why should I learn a pyhsic engine when I want to do that by myself?

Comment: @Arthur For simple physics and collision detection, Box2D is overkill. Even using Box2D, writing some collision tests yourself is educational and will help when debugging.

Comment: Could you describe *what your approach is* rather than what your code is? Often the problem with collision detection isn't with the code you've written, but the way you're thinking about it.

Comment: My approach is to check first if the boundaries of the ``Brick`` and the ``Ball`` intersects, if it intersected then I define the border lines from that ``Brick`` and check which line was intersected to determine from which side it was hit.

Comment: @Anko While I practically agree with you, I find that doing this is more time efficient than explaining that you actually need to (not check once per frame) but try to predict when the next collision will happen and also realize that the ball may hit the (pointy) corner instead of hitting one of the flat sides which should result in different behavior than hitting a flat side would. Also I would like to add that the honing the skills needed to properly use box2d is far more practical than practicing in writing poor untested collision code yourself.

Comment: @user42 You can edit the question to add that, but it's still insufficient detail. Why are you doing `intersectsLine` checks? What if the ball intersects with multiple lines? What if the ball is completely inside a block?

Comment: The ``intersectsLine`` checks determine which side was hit, yes, the problem with the strange collisions occurs if it intersects with multiple lines. And the ball isn't fast enough to completely get inside a block.

Comment: @user42 How will you know how far is the ball is inside the block? Do you want to consider the fact that the ball is circular, or are you happy to treat it as a square? I recommend reading up on [Separating Axis Theorem](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html). It's a widely used and robust method.

Comment: @Anko I could get the intersection rectangle and there I have width and height how far the ball would be inside.

Comment: @user42 Yep, sounds good. Interestingly, that same method also tells you *whether the collision has happened* and *from what direction*. Do you need the `intersectsLine` checks?

Comment: I tried checking it with just x and y coords, but that didn't work like expected, so I thought the easiest option would be to just check the border lines.

Comment: The longer I think about it the more I think that the intersection rectangle would be the better approach... would you like to post an answer for that so I can give credit?

Comment: Off-topic? Well... never mind, could fix that issue thanks to Anko.

Comment: @Anko Now I realize you misunderstand me completely (possibly cause I explained it incorrectly). I was not arguing whether continuous or discrete (predicting in advance or treating the collision as it happens is the way to go). I was noting that flipping the speed on the supposed axis of the collision during an arbitrary discrete time when the collision is detected was not the way to go in my opinion. You need to backtrack to the moment the collision happened and position the ball at that point and handle the collision from that point in time.

Comment: @Arthur Ah yes, *only* flipping the velocity would give occasional frames where the ball is inside a block; it wouldn't be collision detection so much as... just collision. I agree with that. (Sorry for all the confusion; everyone's comments are split between the answers and question. I think this is what is meant by discussion questions not fitting the SE format.)

Answer (score 1):

I see your code uses `else if` for all the intersection checks. If the ball moves at a decent speed, it is very likely that it will collide with several lines (for example, left and top), but your code will only allow it to collide with one side at the time, resulting in erronous velocities from time to time.

Note that errors can still happen even if you remove the `else` before the if, if your ball moves fast enough, so that it can move "through" a brick from loop cycle to loop cycle. To fix that, you will have to "look ahead" in time to determine the time a collision would occur.

Comment: Still strange collisions if it hits one of the edges :(

Comment: I think this correctly identifies the problem, but I think @user42605 could use more details.  Can you elaborate to offer better explanation?

Comment: No if I remove the elses then the ball can collide with more than one site and that is something I don't want. The wrong collision only happens near the edges of the Block.

Comment: @user42605 You are assuming that the ball's movement is "perfect", in that you have pixel-perfect control of where it is. Most likely, you will not have this, but it will move several pixels pr. loop cycle. If it comes down from the top (on the left-ish side of the brick), it will logically cross the top-line first, but if close enough to the corner, it will cross the left line too. Since the left check is first, - it will look like it came from the left in your hit checks.